# Jquery backbutton handler working in browser but not on device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am writing a phonegap app for android and iOS and I'm handling the backbutton as follows with various functions in my app:

```
$(document).unbind("backbutton");
$(document).bind("backbutton", myFunc);
```

Some of the functions use window.location.replace("XXXX.html"); in order to redirect to a new page.

This all works perfectly in a browser using Ripple Emulator but when I use genymotion or an android device I get some strange results where the app will move to the wrong pages or exit the app when it should go back a page.

Any ideas? :(